# Bootstrap modal form validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I need to validate a field and show message to error message control on bootstrap modal form. When I click Update Row button show error message on browser popup after close dialog. It should'nt close dialog to input data to Quantity. Partial Refresh for repeat table data so I cant refresh panel in dialog.

```
         <div id="InvRow" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close"
                                    data-dismiss="modal">
                                </button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">
                                    Invoice Row
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                    <xp:panel id="pnlrow">
                    <xp:table>
                        <xp:tr>
                            <xp:td>
                                <xp:label value="Description :"
                                    id="label13">
                                </xp:label>
                            </xp:td>
                            <xp:td>
                            <xp:inputText id="RestipDesc" defaultValue=".">

                                </xp:inputText>

                            </xp:td>
                            <xp:td></xp:td>
                        </xp:tr>


                        <xp:tr>
                            <xp:td>
                                <xp:label value="Quantity :"
                                    id="label17">
                                </xp:label>
                                </xp:td>
                            <xp:td>
                                <xp:inputText id="RestipQuantity"
                                    required="true" defaultValue="0">

                                    <xp:this.validators>
                                        <xp:validateRequired
                                            message="Quantity Required !!!">
                                        </xp:validateRequired>
                                    </xp:this.validators>
                                    <xp:this.converter>
                                        <xp:convertNumber
                                            type="number">
                                        </xp:convertNumber>
                                    </xp:this.converter>
                                </xp:inputText>

                            </xp:td>

                    </xp:table>
                    <xp:messages id="messages3"></xp:messages>
                    </xp:panel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
        <xp:button value="Update Row" id="button11"  styleClass="btn btn-success">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="false" refreshId="repeatTable">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:UpdateRow();}]]> </xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                            <xp:this.attrs>
                                        <xp:attr name="data-dismiss"
                                            value="modal">
                                        </xp:attr>
                                    </xp:this.attrs>
                        </xp:button>
         <xp:button value="Cancel" id="button5" styleClass ="btn btn-danger">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"  refreshMode="norefresh">                </xp:eventHandler>
                                <xp:this.attrs>
                                        <xp:attr name="data-dismiss"
                                            value="modal">
                                        </xp:attr>
                                    </xp:this.attrs>
                        </xp:button>
                        </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example code you're mixing the clientside automatic dismissal using Bootstrap's `data-dismiss` attribute with XPages partial refreshes: in this setup it will always hide the dialog (whether the fields are validated correctly or not).

I would strongly recommend to use the `xe:dialog` from the Extension Library instead of a 'standard' Bootstrap one. You can keep using
the XPages validators and add some logic to the 'Save' button to determine if the dialog should close or not. If you remove the 'save' attribute from the `xp:button` attributes it won't call the SSJS unless the validations have passed:

```
<xp:button
    value="Update Row"
    id="button11"
    styleClass="btn btn-success">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        immediate="false"
        refreshId="repeatTable">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:if ( UpdateRow() ) {
          getComponent('dialog1').hide();} 
        }]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>              
</xp:button>
```

Comment: hi mark thanks for your help. When i start xpages i used all dialogs xe:dialog when open pages on mobile have problem dialog position and scale/drag so i'm converting all dialogs to bootstrap modal. Problem like this     http://hizliresim.com/5k9VZ5

Comment: Couldn't reproduce that issue on this page (http://bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/dialog.xsp) on Android Lollipop. Might still exist in previous versions though. Did you try using the Bootstrap version embedded in the ExtLib?